# Is it okay to use the 4 pin USB TTL cable instead of the recommended 6 pin USB TTL cable for Intel Galileo?

Tags: microcontrollers, linux, microsoft-windows-iot, intel-galileo

I have only the 4 pin USB TTL cable which has the Rx, Tx, Vcc and GND pins. The 6 pin includes the CTS and RTS pins also, and is specified for use with Intel Galileo board. My question is if I can still use it for normal serial data communications and what will be the difference?

Cable specifics mentioned here:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/intel-galileo-boards/000006343.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CTS and RTS are for flow signaling (Clear To Send) and (Request To Send). If you want to use 4 pins and you find out nothing is flowing through, [you may want to pull CTS down to GND](http://www.summitdata.com/blog/uart-flow-control-rtscts-necessary-proper-operation-wireless-modules/).

In one post OP claimed [I have the Arduinos communicating properly without these pins in use.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38022/what-is-rts-and-cts-flow-control). There OP had Arduinos communicating, they at least can survive without flow control.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- program the UART to not use handshaking,
- or even use software handshaking.
- or connect them permanently to GND.

But for high speed and reliable communication, its best to use the handshaking lines.